# image upload buttons are missing in magento in back end

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am new to Magento...Installed 1.7 community Edition.
I have heard great deal about it and so far I was not impressed..anyway I am trying to add **images** to a **Product** but '**Browse files**' and '**Upload**' **buttons are missing** from the backend. 
I have tried several solutions from online like: 
-copying 'media' folder from 'adminhtml' folder to 'frontend', 
-clearing caches, 
-reforming indices, 
-upgrading to latest flash player.
Nothing seems to work. If any one found solution to this problem please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

These buttons are coming from flash.So check your media folder on following location

```
design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media
```

if there is no media folder then copy from fresh magento

This will solve your problem :)

Comment: There is a good chance you are missing both skin/adminhtml/default/default/media
and
design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media

Answer (score 5):

Magento image uploading issue is related to flash. You need to change the settings of your browser. If you are using chrome,

1. Go chrome settings, or by typing chrome://settings/content
2. Go to  Content settings => flash
3. Turn on Allow site to run flash
4. Turn off ask first

And in Firefox, you don't need to do anything, if your flash player is outdated, you need to update it

Answer (score 5):

Go to 
chrome://settings/content/flash
Add you website url in allow tag

Then refresh your admin panel

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that this question was already answered - no need to repeat and add redundant data. Good luck!

Comment: may I know who are you?

Answer (score 3):

if git is used It's also a good to check .gitignore. it's easy to ignore "media/" instead of "/media/". Deeper media directory contains swf upload buttons.

Answer (score 2):

The upload button is not displayed if JavaScript Variables
*maxUploadFileSizeInBytes* and *maxUploadFileSize* are not properly configured in the following files:

- /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml
- /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/cms/browser/content/uploader.phtml

The variables are declared as follows:

```
maxUploadFileSizeInBytes = <?php echo $this->getDataMaxSizeInBytes() ?>;
maxUploadFileSize = '<?php echo $this->getDataMaxSize() ?>';
```

You can directly edit:

```
maxUploadFileSizeInBytes = 10485760; /* 10.48576 MB */
maxUploadFileSize = '104857600';
```

The *getDataMaxSizeInBytes()* and *getDataMaxSize()* are defined in the file:

- /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php

If your server is running with **HHVM**, the parameters PHP *post_max_size* and *upload_max_filesize* are available under the names *hhvm.server.max_post_size* and *hhvm.server.upload.upload_max_file_size*.

For this he will have to modify the appeal of these parameters in the php file *Uploader.php*, here's how:

Copy the file in the Local Uploader.php architecture:

- /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php

replace the following lines:

```
public function getPostMaxSize()
{
    return ini_get('post_max_size');
}

public function getUploadMaxSize()
{
    return ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
}
```

by the following:

```
public function getPostMaxSize()
{
    $post_max_size = ini_get('post_max_size');
    return $post_max_size ? $post_max_size : ini_get('hhvm.server.max_post_size');
}

public function getUploadMaxSize()
{
    $upload_max_filesize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
    return $upload_max_filesize ? $upload_max_filesize : ini_get('hhvm.server.upload.upload_max_file_size');
}
```

Cordially.
G

Answer (score 0):

I had problem updating to magento 1.9.1, the problem was solved by copying the folder /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/dull

into the new magento instance.

Answer (score 0):

Image upload button is a flash button so you have to download Flash Player.
You can download flash player from following link :
http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/

After installing flash player just need to restart your browser, now you can see the image upload button.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue in admin area. First Enable the Flash of Browser then Recheck.

These buttons use FLASH.

So if your browser does not support flash - then they will not appear.

Ensure that the `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media` folder exists and that there are 2 files within it.

- editor.phtml
- uploader.phtml

Ensure that the `skin/adminhtml/default/default/media` folder exists and that there are 3 files within it.

- flex.swf
- uploader.swf
- uploaderSingle.swf

If you have created your own theme (ie Theme: "mytheme" and Package "mypackage") then ensure the above applies for:

- `app/design/adminhtml/mytheme/mypackage/template/media`
- `skin/adminhtml/mytheme/mypackage/media`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and sorted by doing the following settings in Google Chrome:

Go to menu in the right corner > settings > Advanced > Privacy and Security > Content Settings > Flash > In the allow section click 'ADD' button and type your website URL.

You can check the following URL if any problem:
http://www.alvipixels.co.uk/blog/magento-product-image-upload-button-not-showing.php

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after emptying all my caches in Opera. I just added the exception of my site to the flash setting. Just make sure it is the complete url starting with http(s). I one case I opened the flash player properies and first deleted all content using the delete all button on the advanced tab.

If it is working in one browser it is usually NOT a magento code error in another browser.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome is blocking these buttons because they are flash. follow these steps:

Open Google Chrome
Click on the three dots in the top right hand corner of the browser
Click on settings
Scroll down to advanced and click expand
Scroll down to Privacy and security and click on content setting
Click on flash
Under allow click on add
Copy the homepage link to the website

Here's a tutorial on [fixing Magento upload buttons](https://jonnyjordan.com/blog/how-to-fix-missing-magento-image-upload-button/) in more details